# Create a dialog with customized header and no border in Qt

Tags: css, qt

I need to create a small dialog as follow:

Header is customized: white text, blue background, no X,minimize,maximize button

Border: is very thin like this, also blue (also acceptable) or no border.

```
QcgMyDialog::QcgMyDialog(QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    this->setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
    this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::WindowTitleHint | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);

}
```

How should I do next?

[image]

Comment: You can take inspiration of this [GitHub project](https://github.com/thibDev/RegExpTestor)

Comment: @ThibautB.: thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

use Qt::FramelessWindowHint and then create your own custom buttons.